# Why panel of bootstrap is taking upper area

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Why bootstrap panel is taking header area?  How to solve this problem?

[codepen.io/anon/pen/LEzJZE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LEzJZE)

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
 <section class="container">
  <section class="row">
   <header class="col-lg-12 text-center">
    <h1 class"page-header">Header <small>Join Here</small></h1>
   </header>

   <section class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
     Attention
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi deleniti nam harum autem vitae facilis impedit optio saepe perspiciatis maxime, consectetur sed earum soluta! Perspiciatis voluptas quisquam recusandae officia dolore.</p>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Accept</a>
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline</a>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
     lorem Ipsum <a href="#">Lorem</a>
    </div>
   </section>

   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
     <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9
     </div>   
     <footer>
    
   </footer>
  </section>
 </section>
</body>
```

Comment: post some code here.. describe your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the header tag outside of the div class='row' tag.

```
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
    <header class="col-lg-12 text-center">
        <h1 class"page-header">Header <small>Join Here</small></h1>
    </header>
    <section class="container">
        <section class="row">
            <section class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    Attention
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi deleniti nam harum autem vitae facilis impedit optio saepe perspiciatis maxime, consectetur sed earum soluta! Perspiciatis voluptas quisquam recusandae officia dolore.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Accept</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Decline</a>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                    lorem Ipsum <a href="#">Lorem</a>
                </div>
            </section>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9
            </div>          
            <footer>
            </footer>
        </section>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am just learning bootstrap and you teach me first , Thanks @JBaczuk